# passing string array as hidden value from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, jstl

I am trying to pass String array from one jsp to another. I am using JSTL in my JSP. 
In my first JSP i am doing like this

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(empBean.additionalEmailAddr) gt 0}">
                <c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(empBean.additionalEmailAddr) - 1}" var="ind" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="inbdAdditionalEmailAddr" value="${empBean.additionalEmailAddr[ind]}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
```

and trying to access the values in another jsp as follows

```
<%
    String[] inbdAddEmlAddr = request.getParameter("inbdAdditionalEmailAddr");
%>
```

and i am planning to use JSTL to print the array values.

In the second jsp i am getting type mismatch error. Please help.

Is this the right approach ? Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.getParameter()` returns a `String` which the code attempts to assign to a `String[]`, causing the exception.

Use `request.getParameterValues('inbdAdditionalEmailAddr');` to retrieve parameters as an array.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29).